# Combine several variables

Tags: statistics

a disclaimer beforehand: I don't have a proper math/statistics education background.
 
I have a set of data which comes from the same population (n):
Weight gain (g): mean; SD
Weight (kg): mean; SD
Duration (days): mean; SD

is it possible to combine those variables into a new predefined variable called
weight gain rate (g kg^-1 day^-1)
and if so, how to find the mean and standard deviation of such variable?

thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have the original data, then yes.  If you just have the means and standard deviations then I would have thought no for the product and quotient.